# Is there any authoritative documentation on R release nicknames?

Tags: r

Somewhere after R 2.1.0, I started noticing short phrases next to the R release number that is displayed on start up.  This turns out to be a release nickname, an undocumented component added to the R.Version variable, accessible with `R.Version$nickname`.

The archives of R-announce show Peter Dalgaard announcing a new release's nickname on several occasions (e.g., [here](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/announce/12/0228.html)) but I don't find any other information. Despite being a list element of the object queried by `R.Version()`, it is not included in  help file for that function.

Is there any documentation on this feature? Ideally I'd like a statement of the system used to determine a release's nickname, but any authoritative reference would be great.

Comment: I have edited this question to reduce possibility of discussion (changing from 'is there any use and documentation' to 'is there any authoritative documentation') in the hopes of getting it reopened.

Comment: Most people don't use a "system" to determine their practice of "fun".  This might be like that. ;)

Comment: there's a webscraping project here for someone: start at `url0 <- "http://www.googlesyndicatedsearch.com/u/newcastlemaths?q=%22is+released+from+Peter+Dalgaard%22&sa=Google+Search"` and go from there ...

Comment: You can look at the commit history of the `VERSION-NICK` file in the sources, but from that it seems to be whatever Peter Dalgaard wants it to be.

Comment: @BrianDiggs: And that's what `src/include/Makevars.in` uses to create `Rversion.h`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In response to an email asking if there is a system to the names, Peter Dalgaard states there is

> "No system (except that they should be in season at release time)"

Thus, they are not alphabetical or otherwise ordinal -- there is apparently not a way to infer the order of releases from their nicknames.

There is, however, the appearance of a possible general theme:

- r-devel  (unreleased development version) Unsuffered Consequences
- 2.14.0   (2011-10-31) [Great Pumpkin](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2011/000544.html)
- 2.14.1   (2011-12-22) [December Snowflakes](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2011/000548.html)
- 2.14.2   (2012-02-29) [Gift-Getting Season](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2012/000550.html)
- 2.15.0   (2012-03-30) [Easter Beagle](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2012/000551.html)
- 2.15.1   (2012-06-22) [Roasted Marshmallows](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2012/000554.html)
- 2.15.2   (2012-10-26) [Trick or Treat](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2012/000557.html)
- 2.15.3   (2013-03-01) [Security Blanket](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2013/000560.html)
- 3.0.0    (2013-04-03) [Masked Marvel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2013/000561.html)
- 3.0.1    (2013-05-16) [Good Sport](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2013/000563.html)
- 3.0.2    (2013-09-25) [Frisbee Sailing](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2013/000567.html)
- 3.0.3    (2014-03-06) [Warm Puppy](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2014/000569.html)
- 3.1.0    (2014-04-10) [Spring Dance](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2014/000572.html)
- 3.1.1    (2014-07-10) [Sock it to Me](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2014/000575.html)
- 3.1.2    (2014-10-31) [Pumpkin Helmet](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2014/000578.html)
- 3.1.3    (2015-03-09) [Smooth Sidewalk](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2015/000582.html)
- 3.2.0    (2015-04-16) [Full of Ingredients](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2015/000583.html)
- 3.2.1    (2015-06-18) [World-Famous Astronaut](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2015/000586.html)
- 3.2.2    (2015-08-14) [Fire Safety](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2015/000589.html)
- 3.2.3    (2015-12-10) [Wooden Christmas-Tree](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2015/000593.html)
- 3.2.4    (2016-03-11) [Very Secure Dishes](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2016/000597.html)
- 3.2.5    (2016-04-11) [Very, Very Secure Dishes](https://svn.r-project.org/R/tags/R-3-2-5/VERSION-NICK) (a [rebadged](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2016/000601.html) [3.2.4-revised](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2016/000598.html))
- 3.3.0    (2016-05-03) [Supposedly Educational](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2016/000602.html)
- 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) [Bug in Your Hair](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2016/000604.html)
- 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) [Sincere Pumpkin Patch](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2016/000608.html)
- 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) [Another Canoe](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2017/000611.html)
- 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) [You Stupid Darkness](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2017/000612.html)
- 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) [Single Candle](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2017/000616.html)
- 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) [Short Summer](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2017/000619.html)
- 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) [Kite-Eating Tree](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2017/000623.html)
- 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) [Someone to Lean On](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2018/000626.html)
- 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) [Joy in Playing](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2018/000628.html)
- 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) [Feather Spray](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2018/000630.html)
- 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) [Eggshell Igloo](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2018/000634.html)
- 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) [Great Truth](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2019/000638.html)
- 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) [Planting of a Tree](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2019/000641.html)
- 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) [Action of the Toes](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2019/000643.html)
- 3.6.2 (2019-12-12) [Dark and Stormy Night](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2019/000647.html)
- 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) [Holding the Windsock](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2020/000650.html)
- 4.0.0 (2020-04-24) [Arbor Day](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2020/000653.html)
- 4.0.1 (2020-06-06) [See Things Now](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2020/000655.html)
- 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) [Taking Off Again](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2020/000658.html)
- 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) [Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2020/000662.html)
- 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) [Lost Library Book](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2021/000664.html)
- 4.0.5 (2021-03-31) [Shake and Throw](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2021/000668.html)
- 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) [Camp Pontanezen](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2021/000670.html)
- 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) [Kick Things](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2021/000672.html)
- 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) [Bird Hippie](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2021/000677.html)
- 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) [One Push-Up](https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2021/000677.html)
- 4.2.0 (2022-04-22) [Vigorous Calisthenics](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2022/000683.html)
- 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) [Funny-Looking Kid](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2022/000685.html)
- 4.2.2 (2022-10-31) [Innocent and Trusting](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2022/000686.html)
- 4.2.3 (2023-03-15) [Shortstop Beagle](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2023/000689.html)
- 4.3.0 (2023-04-21) [Already Tomorrow](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2023/000691.html)
- 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) [Beagle Scouts](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2023/000694.html)
- 4.3.2 (2023-10-31) [Eye Holes](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2023/000697.html)

As no one has uncovered any documentation, I'll tentatively accept my own answer.

Comment: and that's the full history, I think ... doesn't look like there were any nicknames prior to 2.14.  Since major releases are now scheduled for spring we could end up with a lot more spring-themed nicknames ...

Comment: I strongly suspect that a (loose) common theme here is the cartoon Peanuts.

Comment: I did this timeline a while back http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_timeline_r/.

Comment: Please, when editing, don't (let your spell checker) change "unsuffered" to "unbuffered". Already happened twice.

Answer (score 55):

I'm surprised @joran didn't follow up on his own hint in the comments section. All of the version names can be traced directly to the Peanuts cartoon. I stumbled upon the evidence in my daily peanuts desktop calendar:

[image]

I provided an answer here:
https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-reasons-behind-the-release-names-of-the-various-R-iterations.

A few more examples:

(Frisbee Sailing)

[image]

[image]

(World Famous Astronaut)

[image]

It's too easy - just Google the version names followed by "Peanuts" and you'll find all of them!

The follow up question to this is: Who in the R Core Team loves Peanuts and got this started?

Comment: My entirely unsubstantiated hunch is that Peter Dalgaard actually names the releases, so he's probably just being a little coy in denying any system to it.

Comment: Yeah, from my email exchange with him in 2012, I was led to believe that Dalgaard names them thematically (though not systematically) and considers the theme obvious.  I agreed with the theme's obviousness (anyone who didn't have a suspicion at "Great Pumpkin" and a certainty at "Easter Beagle" just hadn't heard of Peanuts). So I decided to hint at it and leave it to the reader as a fun exercise.

Answer (score 24):

Peter Delgaard has confirmed that the release names are taken from the Peanuts comics, in his talk made at useR!2018: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1vTSdRolgI

At about 8 minutes in is when he starts talking about the release names (screenshot from the video):

[image]

He also references this site for an explanation of the releases: http://livefreeordichotomize.com/2018/04/23/r-release-names/

Comment: But how to get from "Unsuffered Consequences" to "December Snowflakes"? Is there an algorithm? Hard to believe it's arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Other responses have pointed that all of the release names are references to Peanuts strips/films. [R release names](https://livefreeordichotomize.com/2017/09/28/r-release-names/) is a blog page with reference to each comic strip for each version name.

From the page:

> r-devel (unreleased development version) Unsuffered Consequences
>
> Reference: Peanuts August 17, 1967
>
> 2.14.0 (2011-10-31) Great Pumpkin
>
> Reference: Peanuts October 29, 1973
>
> 2.14.1 (2011-12-22) December Snowflakes
>
> Reference: A Charlie Brown Christmas
>
> This is very close to the Peanuts January 5, 1960, however they
> mention January snowflakes rather than December. The “December
> Snowflakes” quote is from A Charlie Brown Christmas.
>
> 2.14.2 (2012-02-29) Gift-Getting Season
>
> Reference: This is a line Lucy says in the short film It’s the Easter
> Beagle, Charlie Brown! – referring to Easter as the “gift-getting
> season”.
>
> 2.15.0 (2012-03-30) Easter Beagle
>
> Reference: Peanuts April 11, 1971
>
> This also likely references the It’s the Easter Beagle, Charlie
> Brown!.
>
> 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) Roasted Marshmallows
>
> Reference: Peanuts June 6, 1987
>
> 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) Trick or Treat
>
> Reference: Peanuts October 31, 1969
>
> 2.15.3 (2013-03-01) Security Blanket
>
> Reference: Peanuts October 23, 1965
>
> 3.0.0 (2013-04-03) Masked Marvel
>
> Reference: Peanuts June 23, 1981
>
> Edit: Got some insider info from the source himself that this is from
> Charlie Brown and Snoopy Show!
>
> Source MoviesAfterMidnight
> 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) Good Sport
>
> Reference: You’re a Good Sport, Charlie Brown
>
> This is likely from the film You’re a Good Sport Charlie Brown,
> however there Peanuts November 22, 1953 does refer to being a “Good
> Sport” as well!
>
> 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) Frisbee Sailing
>
> Reference: Peanuts September 3, 1971
>
> 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) Spring Dance
>
> Reference: Peanuts March 22, 1971
>
> Sock it to me Source ebay
> 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) Sock it to Me
>
> Reference: This seems to be referring to a mini jigsaw puzzle,
> available on ebay!
>
> Source MoviesAfterMidnight
> 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) Pumpkin Helmet
>
> Reference: You’re a Good Sport, Charlie Brown
>
> It’s a bit later in the clip, around 16:45.
>
> Source Something to be Found
> 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) Smooth Sidewalk
>
> Reference: This is a page from the Happiness is a Warm Puppy book.
>
> 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) Full of Ingredients
>
> Reference: Peanuts April 7, 1966
>
> 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) World-Famous Astronaut
>
> Reference: Peanuts March 10, 1969
>
> Source Business Wire
> 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) Fire Safety
>
> Reference: It seems that MetLife created a Peanuts themed Fire Saftey
> Brochure coloring and activity book.
>
> 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) Wooden Christmas-Tree
>
> Reference: This is a line from A Charlie Brown Christmas – Linus says
> “Gee, I didn’t know they still made wooden Christmas trees”.
>
> 3.2.4 (2016-03-11) Very Secure Dishes
>
> Reference: Peanuts February 20, 1964
>
> 3.2.5 (2016-04-11) Very, Very Secure Dishes (a rebadged 3.2.4-revised)
>
> I assume this is still a reference to Peanuts February 20, 1964
>
> 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) Supposedly Educational
>
> Reference: Peanuts May 7, 1971
>
> 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) Bug in Your Hair
>
> Reference: Peanuts June 15, 1967
>
> 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) Sincere Pumpkin Patch
>
> Reference: Peanuts Oct 30, 1968
>
> 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) Another Canoe
>
> Reference: Peanuts June 29, 1966
>
> 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) You Stupid Darkness
>
> Reference: Peanuts September 9, 1965
>
> 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) Single Candle
>
> Reference: Peanuts September 9, 1965
>
> 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) Short Summer
>
> Reference: It was a Short Summer, Charlie Brown
>
> 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) Kite-eating Tree
>
> Reference: Peanuts February 19, 1967
>
> Peter Dalgaard made a gif to commemorate the momentous occasion!
>
> Source catawiki auctions
> 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) Someone to Lean On
>
> Reference: Peanuts Figurine (1971). There are a couple of different
> versions of this, some with Charlie Brown and Snoopy, one with Linus
> and Snoopy, and one with Woodstock and Snoopy. Many of them were
> Hallmark cards, but there was also a badge and this figurine. The
> oldest (dated) one I could find was this one from 1971, so we went
> with that!
>
> 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) Joy in Playing
>
> Reference: Peanuts January 27, 1973
>
> 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) Feather Spray
>
> Reference: Peanuts March 9, 1972